# Laravel form problems

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Sory for bad english.

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('TaskController@stateChange', $task->id, Auth::id(), 2, 3, 4), 'method' => 'POST', 'role' => 'form')) }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></span> Сдать задачу</button>
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

if i try to use this code, REQUEST_URI have this viev

> /task/stateChange/2/1/2/3?4

after this:

> Missing argument 5 for TaskController::stateChange()

function:
`public function    stateChange($taskId, $userId, $stateId, $roleId, $statusId)`

What i must to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's no way we can fix this if we don't know what you want.

Comment: From your Error I can realize that you are not sending the 5th argument to TaskController->stateChange i.e., the $statusId is not reaching it

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with your route. Can you please add the relevant code from `routes.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add exactly 5 params in your `routes.php` file
Example:

```
Route::('stateChange/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}/{five}', ['as' => 'YourController@yourMethod']);
```

If you need optional params, you need add `?` in brackets.

```
Route::('stateChange/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}/{five}/{six?}', ['as' => 'YourController@yourMethod']);
```

And your method would looks like:

```
yourMethod($one, $two, $three, $four, $five, $six = null)
```